# Using Find in Word from a List in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am working on an automated peer review macro that would check for certain words and highlight them in a Microsoft Word document. However, I am looking to substitute the `WordList = Split(" is , are ,", ",")` with a list I created in excel. This would be easier for me to add new words instead of manually typing the words I want highlighted in the code.

For example: A1 has the word " is ", so I am hoping it would be something like `Wordlist = Split("A1, A2")`

or something like `Exlist = Range("A1:A2").value` so `WordList = Split(ExList)`

Is something like that possible? Thank you for your help.

```
  Sub PeerReview()

  Dim r As Range
  Dim WordList() As String
  Dim a As Long

  Dim Doc As Document
  Dim Response As Integer

  'This code will search through all of the open word documents and ask you which ones you would like to peer review.
   For Each Doc In Documents
      'MsgBox Doc
      Response = MsgBox(prompt:="Do you want to peer review " & Doc & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
      If Response = vbNo Then GoTo ShortCut

      'This code will highlight words that do not belong in the paragraph
      WordList = Split(" is , are ,", ",") 'List of words to check for when it is peer-reviewing
      Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdPink *'Highlight when found*
      For a = 0 To UBound(WordList())
          Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
          With r.Find
            .Text = WordList(a)
            .Replacement.Highlight = wdYellow
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
          End With
      Next 'next word

ShortCut:
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Not too familiar with word-vba however why use Split? Wouldn't something like this work better.. Array("is, "are") and use the Instr Function or Like to find if the word contains anything in the array.

Comment: So are you running the macro from an Excel workbook to operate on a Word document, or from a Word document that pulls keywords (and possibly other configuration info) from an Excel workbook?

Comment: Though I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to achieve, maybe this helps. You can have a word list in Excel, say in A1:A10. Then declare and array of variants: `Dim WordList() as Variant`. After that fill the array from an Excel Range: `WordList = Range("A1:A10")`. Note that this creates a 2-D array, so you access elements from column 1: `WordList(n,1)`. This reads directly from a Range to an Array; no need for Split.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit in maintaining the list in Excel rather than, say in a `Const` like `Const SEARCH_WORDS = " is , are "` and then just using `Split` on that:  `WordList = Split(SEARCH_WORDS, ",")`.  Using a separate file seems like it would be even more of a maintenance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways to retrieve an array of words from an external file (Word, Excel, and Text Files) in MS Word.  Reading from the text file is by far the fastest.

Results

- Word:  0.328125 Seconds
- Excel: 1.359130859375 Seconds
- Text:  0.008056640625 Seconds

---

```
----------    ----------
Get Word List from Word Document
Start Time:12/1/2007 11:03:56 PM 
End Time:9/1/2016 12:53:16 AM 
Duration:0.328125 Seconds
------------------------------

----------    ----------
Get Word List from Excel
Start Time:12/1/2007 3:05:49 PM 
End Time:9/1/2016 12:53:17 AM 
Duration:1.359130859375 Seconds
------------------------------

----------    ----------
Get Word List from Text Document
Start Time:11/30/2007 6:16:01 AM 
End Time:9/1/2016 12:53:17 AM 
Duration:0.008056640625 Seconds
------------------------------
```

### Unit Test

```
Sub TestWordList()
    Dim arData

    EventsTimer "Get Word List from Word Document"
    arData = GetWordsListDoc
    'Debug.Print Join(arData, ",")
    EventsTimer "Get Word List from Word Document"

    EventsTimer "Get Word List from Excel"
    arData = GetWordsListXL
    'Debug.Print Join(arData, ",")
    EventsTimer "Get Word List from Excel"

    EventsTimer "Get Word List from Text Document"
    arData = GetWordsListTxt
    'Debug.Print Join(arData, ",")
    EventsTimer "Get Word List from Text Document"

End Sub
```

### Event Timer

```
Sub EventsTimer(Optional EventName As String)
    Static dict As Object
    If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If dict.Exists(EventName) Then
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print String(10, "-"), String(10, "-")
        Debug.Print EventName
        Debug.Print ; "Start Time:"; ; Now - dict(EventName)
        Debug.Print ; "End Time:"; ; Now
        Debug.Print ; "Duration:"; ; Timer - dict(EventName) & " Seconds"
        Debug.Print String(10, "-"); String(10, "-"); String(10, "-")
        dict.Remove EventName
    Else
        dict.Add EventName, CDbl(Timer)
    End If

    If dict.Count = 0 Then Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

### Functions to retrieve a word list from MS Word, Ms Excel and a Text File.

```
Function GetWordsListDoc()
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Wordlist\WordList.docx"

    Dim doc As Word.Document, oWords As Word.Words
    Dim x As Long
    Dim arData

    Set doc = Application.Documents.Open(FileName:=FilePath, ReadOnly:=True)

    Set oWords = doc.Words

    ReDim arData(oWords.Count - 1)

    For x = 1 To oWords.Count
        arData(x - 1) = Trim(oWords.Item(x))
    Next

    doc.Close False

    GetWordsListDoc = arData

End Function

Function GetWordsListXL()
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Wordlist\WordsList.xlsb"
    Const xlUp = -4162
    Dim arData
    Dim x As Long
    Dim oExcel As Object, oWorkbook As Object
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With oExcel
        .Visible = False
        Set oWorkbook = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    End With

    With oWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        arData = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
        arData = oExcel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arData)
    End With

    oWorkbook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit

    GetWordsListXL = arData

End Function

Function GetWordsListTxt()
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Wordlist\WordList.txt"
    Dim arData, f, fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePath)

    arData = Split(f.ReadAll, vbNewLine)

    GetWordsListTxt = arData

End Function
```